# Best DynamoDB Structure for Implementation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on a save application, basically the user could go to an article and click save to store it in his profile. Instead of using a relational database the Application currently is using dynamodb. Each article has a specific type of article. The way the structure is currently used for this application is:

```
user-id [string][DynamoDBHashKey]
type-of-article [string]  [DynamoDBRangeKey]
json [string]
```

user-id is the unique identifier for the user, type-of-article is well.. the type of the article, and the json is all the articles saved in a json format. the json format being:

```
[{article-id: timestamp}, {article-id: timestamp}]
  Article #1 ^             Article #2 ^
```

article-id is (again) the article unique identifier and timestamp is the timestamp for when that article was stored .

**Note** This was done before dynamodb started supporting for json documents as Map and Lists. And the code is not mine.. It was already done..

So when the application needs to remove an article from saved It calls dynamo to get the json modify the json and then stores it again. When is going to add a new article it does the same thing. Now a problem appeared when I wanted to display all the articles ordered by the timestamps. I had to call to get all the types and merge them in a dictionary to sort them. (In the user profile I need to show all saved articles, no matter what type, sorted) Now the application is taking more than 700 or 900 ms to respond.

Personally I don't think this is the best way to approach this. So i'm thinking on rewriting the previous code to implement the new features from dynamodb (List and Maps). Now my idea for the structure in dynamodb is like this:

```
user-id [string]  [DynamoDBHashKey]
saved-articles [List]
    article-type_1
        article_1 [Map] {id: article-id, timestamp: date}
        article_2 [Map] {id: article-id, timestamp: date}
    article-type_2
        article_1 [Map] {id: article-id, timestamp: date}
```

But i'm relatively new to dynamodb, I made some test code to store this in dynamo using list and maps. I did it using the low level api and with the Object Persistence Model.

Now, my question is: is this a better approach or if is not why ? and what would be the better approach.

This way I think I can use the low level Api to only get the saved-articles of article-type #2. Or if I need them all I just call it all.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with a solution that is a bit more NoSQL-like.  For NoSQL databases, if you have nested data models and/or updating existing records, those are often indicators that your data model can be optimized.  I really see 2 objects that your application is using, 'users' and 'articles'.  I would avoid a nested data model and updating existing records by doing the following:

**'user' table**

- user id as hash key

**'article' table**

- article id as hash key
- timestamp as range key
- user id (used in global secondary index described below)
- article type and any other attributes would be non-key attributes

You'd also have a global secondary index on the article table that would allow you to search for articles by user id, which would look like something (assuming you want a user's articles sorted by date):

- user id as hash key
- timestamp as range key
- article id as projected attribute

With this model, you never need to go back and edit existing records, you just add records that are 'edited' as new records, and you take the one with the most recent timestamp as your current version.

One thing to remember with NoSQL is that storage space is cheap, reads are cheap, but editing existing records are usually expensive and undesirable operations.